# Oracle Uptime Query

Tags: oracle

Is there a way for a non admin user to check the uptime of an Oracle instance? I.e. I don't have sysdba privileges.

Comment: It's Oracle 10g normally. Operating system varies...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question specifies "non admin user" so I'm afraid the answer is probably no.  The usual mechanisms require selecting from V$ views - V$INSTANCE or V$SESSION.  Neither of these are granted to PUBLIC by default.

If you ask your DBA nicely they might be prepared to grant you access to those views, or at least write a wrapping function (or functions) to expose those values.

Answer (score 21):

Try this. It doesn't require an admin user, although `SELECT` access to the `v_$instance` table.

```
SELECT to_char(startup_time,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "DB Startup Time"
FROM sys.v_$instance;
```

Or, if you assume that PMON startup time is the same as the database startup time, you can get the uptime like this:

```
SELECT to_char(logon_time,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM v$session
WHERE sid=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query will show you [Oracle database uptime](https://orahow.com/find-oracle-database-uptime-startup-history/) and startup history.

```
SELECT host_name, instance_name,TO_CHAR(startup_time, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') startup_time, FLOOR(sysdate-startup_time) days FROM sys.v_$instance;


select * from ( select STARTUP_TIME FROM dba_hist_database_instance ORDER BY startup_time DESC) WHERE rownum <10;
```

Answer (score 0):

The PMON's sid is not always equal to 1. So it is better to use the query:

```
SELECT t.LOGON_TIME FROM v$session t where upper(t.PROGRAM) like ('%PMON%')
```

it works for 11.2.0.4 and 12.1.0.2 on solaris and linux redhat.

Answer (score -3):

I'd suggest something like [**this**](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_uptime.htm) - but you should give more details, for example what OS you are on, and what version of Oracle.